# How to add classes to post_class?

Tags: post-class

In the following code I would like to remove the div that wrap all the code and pass its class to article, but I do not know how to pass the variable $termString inside the post_class.

Can anybody help me?

```
<div class="<?php echo $termsString;?>">
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('card'); ?>>
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-fluid card-img-top')); ?>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="card-body text-right">
            <h6 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h6>
            <p>Text description for this item</p>
        </div>
        <a class="card-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"></a>  
    </article>
</div>
```

So, I have this now, and it is what I expected:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('card grid-item wow fadeInUp ' . $termsString); ?>>
```

but I also need to add to these classes another class that comes from a custom field which name is "columns" and with value "col-12".

This is what I am trying, but I think there's some syntax error, the result I see from the Firefox inspector is "Array" instead of the value of "columns":

```
<?php $custom_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'columns', true); ?>
                    <?php
                        $classes = array(
                            'card',
                            'grid-item',
                            'wow',
                            'fadeInUp',
                            $termsString,
                            $custom_values
                        );
                    ?>
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
```

**Edit:** get_post_meta requires a third parameter, "false" returns the Array (default), "true" returns only the first result (NOT as an array). Now it is working! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may want to wrap `$termsString` in the `esc_attr` function for security reasons, that way it's escaped

Comment: The `post_class()` function already runs `esc_attr()` on all elements AFAIK.

Answer (score 5):

The `post_class` function does also accept an array of classes. You can pass them to the function as follows:

```
$classes = [
    'card',
    'grid-item',
    'wow',
    'fadeInUp',
    $termsString
];

<div <?php post_class ( $classes ); ?>>
   ...
</div>
```

You can store the custom field's value inside a variable, and then pass it to the function just like any other value.

Comment: Something like this? <?php $custom_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'columns'); ?> $classes = [
    'card',
    'grid-item',
    'wow',
    'fadeInUp',
    $termsString, $custom_values
];

<div <?php post_class ( $classes ); ?>>
   ...
</div>

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how.

Comment: It is not working, there is some error that I can not detect, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use `post_class( 'card ' . $termString )`.

The function accepts arrays and strings, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/

You can also use the post_class filter to add more classes if you prefer that way.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to put the space after "card".

How can I include my custom field without using filters?

Comment: Using your custom meta value as the post class? That works the same way. An example `post_class( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_meta_key', true ) )`. If that‘s not what you meant, please update your question accordingly :-)

Comment: I just edited it.